# Capture HTML Drop Down Value

Tags: python, python-2.7, web, bottle

I am learning to use bottle to create web applications. I am new to HTML.

How do I capture drop down values? In a simple example I ask the user to input how many people he would like to record the ages of. This looks as follows:

```
import bottle as bt
@bt.route('/persons', method = 'GET')
def count_persons():
    return '''
        <h3>We are going to collect data on the ages of a number of people</h3>
        <p>Use the drop down box below to select the number of people who's age you would like to record.</p>
        <p>
        <select id="persons">
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        </select, name = "persons">
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="continue" value="continue">
    '''

@bt.route('/persons', method = 'POST')
def render_template():
    persons = bt.request.GET.get('persons', '')
    return 'You have chosen ' + str(persons)

bt.run(host = 'localhost', port = 8080, debug = True)
```

I have also tried `bt.request.forms('persons')`. It seems to me that the selected value should be accessible by the `id` of the dropdown. Is that not right?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an html form so that the data is sent to the server.

```
import bottle as bt
@bt.route('/persons', method = 'GET')
def count_persons():
    return '''
        <form action="/persons" method="post">
            <h3>We are going to collect data on the ages of a number of people</h3>
            <p>Use the drop down box below to select the number of people who's age you would like to record.</p>
            <p>
            <select id="persons">
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            </select, name = "persons">
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" name="continue" value="continue">
        </form>
    '''

@bt.route('/persons', method = 'POST')
def render_template():
    persons = bt.request.POST.get('persons', '')
    return 'You have chosen ' + str(persons)

bt.run(host = 'localhost', port = 8080, debug = True)
```

Clicking the submit button send the data to the server and will also cause the page to be reloaded. If you don't want the page to be reloaded you have to use an XmlHttpRequest.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am still not totally clear to be honest. Based upon the input which I capture I will then return a form to the user that is saved in a .tpl file, that uses the integer value from the dropdown to create the correct form. So I guess I do not want it to reload. In the example I gave after sumbission I just wanted to return a simple string as an experiment. Am I going about this all wrong? I think I fundamentally do not understand HTTP methods and this is the main issue.